# global variable not access in another file

Tags: javascript, php

I declare a global variable in JavaScript in header.php file but it is not accessible in footer.php file

Code:

**header.php**

```
<?php define('BASE_URL','https://example.com'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascipt">
            var baseUrl = { url:"<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>" };
        </script>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     </head>
     <body>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once("templates/header.php");
require_once("templates/footer.php");
```

**footer.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(baseUrl.url);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

At here I try to access baseUrl variable in footer.php file but I get this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: baseUrl is not defined

Looking for help!

Comment: You are missing a `<body>` tag.

Comment: @Hackerman just edited my question no I don't miss that tag

Comment: Should work fine !

Comment: @adeneo But it doesn't work fine I get error which I mentioned

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I also tried to declare that variable in footer.php file but get same error

Comment: Simple typo, it is then, good eyes on Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misspelled `type="text/javascript"`. Fix that and it should work.

Comment: aah, what a silly mistake was done by me. thank you so much :)

Comment: On that note, HTML5 spec defaults to the type "text/javascript," so declaring it is redundant, unless you want to be extra specific for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, you wrote `javascipt` instead of `javascript` in the `type="..."` attribute.